# How to make specific field disabled on node submit, but enabled on node edit?

Tags: 7, entities

In content type `testtype` I have 2 required field: `field_one` & `field_two`.

I need to make `field_one` only enabled on node submit, while `field_two` only enabled on node edit.

So, when submitting, we can only see `field_one`, and when editing, we can only see `field_two`

Comment: Got it using `form_alter`

Comment: The difference between submit and edit is not clear in your question.

Comment: @David Thomas, Node submit `node/add/testtype`, while node edit `node/<nodeid>/edit`. I've solved the problem by `form_alter`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can solve this problem in different ways.

The first is quite easy: you can show/hide the fields from CSS.

When you create a node, the default body classes contain this CSS class: "page-node-add". Instead when you edit a node you'll have the class "page-node-edit".

So you can add this CSS code:

```
.page-node-add .field_two{ display:none } 
.page-node-edit .field_one{ display:none }
```

This solution is not elegant and it could be a potential security hole.

A better solution is to implement hook_form_alter() from your theme or from a custom module.

The code could be something like:

```
function yourmodulename_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'testtype_node_form' && arg(1) == 'add' ) {
    $form['field_two']['#access'] = 0;
  }
  if ($form_id == 'testtype_node_form' && arg(2) == 'edit' ) {
    $form['field_one']['#access'] = 0;
  }
}
```

Good work!

Answer (score 0):

I had almost the same situation today and [field permission](http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions) did the job perfectly.